# Django minimal queryset of last objects where exactly n records meets condition

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.0

I have a model `Invoice`:

```
class Invoice(Model):
    datetime = DateTimeField(..)
    paid = BooleanField(..)
```

I want to get queryset of n latest `Invoices` where `paid = True` but I want to include `paid = False` `Invoices` if there are some between n latest paid `Invoices`.

So I want minimal queryset of latest `Invoices` where there is exactly `n` of them paid.

Example:

We have 8 invoices ordered by `("-created","-id")`:

```
datetime = 15.04.2018 14:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 15.04.2018 13:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 14.04.2018 14:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 14.04.2018 14:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 13.04.2018 14:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 13.04.2018 14:00
paid = False
______________
datetime = 13.04.2018 14:00
paid = True
______________
datetime = 13.04.2018 14:00
paid = False
______________
```

If I want a queryset of 6 latest paid Invoices I will get all of them except the last one. The queryset will include 6th `Invoice` even if it's not paid yet.

```
latest_n_paid = Invoice.objects.get(paid=True)[:n]
first_paid_from_latest_n_paid = latest_n_paid.last()
queryset = Invoice objects.filter(datetime__gte=first_paid_from_latest_n_paid.datetime)
```

This would not work because it would return all `Invoices` since the last one has the same `datetime` as last paid `Invoice`.

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT**

I would like to do this on a database level instead of looping over queryset if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the expected behavior here. You want to query for the latest N invoices that are `paid`. How do the ones that are `paid=False` come into play here? Maybe you can add an example of expected vs actual output?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution :

```
query_set = Invoice.objects.order_by('-paid','-datetime')[:n]
```

Comment: and. Please don't forget estimate)